# Was there any indication that Connie, in cut scenes or novels, contemplated vengeance upon Michael?

Tags: the-godfather, the-godfather-2, the-godfather-3

Although it was Fredo who was caught betraying his brother, it was Connie who clearly really hated Michael (although whether she was really justified in this is another question).

Two major reasons are firstly the execution of her husband and much later, indeed the killing of their sibling whom Connie clearly loved.

Despite the foregoing, she continued to have contact with Michael (who well knew why -- she needed his money and I guess he provided it out of, probably, a sense that his father would have done so and also, their mother was still alive -- but he continued to have contact with her even after their mother's death).

Was there an indication that Connie at least contemplated cutting off contact with Michael or even something more active, like revenge? And did Michael consider the possibility that she might attempt some sort of revenge for her husband or was he so sure of her dependence on him in addition to the fact that she wielded no power of her own that he discounted this possibility?

Answer (score 3):

### None evident

While Connie may have suspected Michael had Carlo killed (and accused him of the same) and blamed him she seems to have become resigned to the issue.

Equally, Fredo's death was attributed to a boating accident and here this seems to have gone unremarked by Connie who may have feigned ignorance of  the truth.

Nevertheless, there is no evidence that any revenge was anticipated by Connie for Michael's actions.

Equally the novel (and there is only the one, the sequels were not based on additional novels) do not shed any light on this. In fact the movies indicate that Connie became closer to Michael over the second and third movies.

In the second movie she makes it clear that she did try to "punish" Michael by acting out.

> Michael, I hated you for so many years.
>
> I think I did things to myself, to hurt myself, so that you'd know that I could hurt you.

By the time of the third movie, Connie is acting as Michael's "hostess" and confidant in place of Kay who is now remarried.

None of this indicates that any form of actual revenge was contemplated by Connie.

Comment: Connie is thus shown to be a very pragmatic sister.